# Back up personal files when TimeMachine is set to backup other files

Tags: network, finder, backup, time-machine, smb

I run my own samba server on my home desktop. I use MAC for work and personal business. TimeMachine is set up to back up my work folders (on the other, office samba server). I want to back up my personal folder on my SMB server. I connect to this server using finder (connect to server option).

Is there a way to manually backup (e.g. copy-paste) my personal folder in a way rsync does it, e.g. by only updating those files that have been changed?
I don't have good internet at home, and transferring 100Gb of data all the time seems unnecessary.

Alternatively, is there a way to set up timeMachine to backup 1 set of folders to 1 server, and another set of folders to another?

Thanks,
Mikhail

Comment: If you use `rsync` it will automatically copy changed data only.

Comment: @nohillside, thanks, but it only work in terminal, not in finder

Comment: Finder doesn't support incremental backup, it's either `rsync` or a GUI-based solution to run `rsync` in the background. What makes it important to have a Finder-based solution?

Comment: Its more convenient. But I guess creating a bash script is also an option. Thanks

Comment: Carbon copy clone in effect can act as a. Front to r sync